# Selenium, Java - How to click at an element using text?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, click, webdriver

I'm having trouble with clicking at an element, which I find using text which is a variable. This is the code of the page:

```
<div class="recommendedProfileList fl">
<h3>
<ul class="ctrlResearchProfiles">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<span class="profileBtn ctrlSelectDefProfile ctrlClickSubmit" data-value="143" data-form="formChooseProfile" data-profileid="143">Sales manager</span>
<span class="profileTooltip" style="display: none;">
<span class="arrow"/>
<span class="profileTooltipContent">
</span>
```

and the name of the variable is *profile*. This is how I've tried to do this, but did not work:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()=' + profile + ']")));
```

second:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()=' + profile + ']"));
```

also:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("" +profile)).click();
```

Do you know how to click such element?

Comment: Do you try to click on the span element with class "profileBtn" ?

Comment: Yes, and I want to refer to Sales manager. There are few familiar element on the page and data-value is different for each too but I have no idea how to use that one so I've been trying with the name

Comment: Did you debug your code to see if the call to driver.findElement(...) returns the right WebElement instance object?  This may help you to figure out what's wrong.  Does the click has no effect or does the findElement returns the wrong element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there buddy...

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[text()='" + profile + "']")));
```

second:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='" + profile + "']"));
```

The thing that you missed was double quotes to insert ur variable values in xpath.

Comment: your hint worked, the element has been found. it turned out, the element is invisible...